# Using Local Canonical Form to determine Curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, curvature, plane-geometry

I am trying to figure out a question but am having trouble solving it. The question reads:

> Let $\alpha:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ be a regular curve without critical points of order $1$, and let $t_0\in I$. Let $\beta(t)$ be the curve obtained by projecting $\alpha(t)$ onto its osculating plane at $t=t_0$. Show that $\alpha(t)$ and $\beta(t)$ have the same curvature at $t=t_0$.

Now I know I'm supposed to use the Local Canonical Form for this, so the projection of $\alpha(t)$ onto the osculating plane would give:

$$\beta(t)=(t-\frac{\kappa_0}{6}t^3+R_x, \frac{\kappa_0}{2}t^2+\frac{\kappa_0'}{6}t^3+r_y)$$
Where the term $\kappa_0$ denotes the curvature at $\kappa(t_0)$. Am I approaching this right? Would I now compute the curvature of $\beta(t)$ to determine the curvature?

Comment: Back to basic, $$\kappa= \frac{|\mathbf{\dot{r}} \times \mathbf{\ddot{r}}|}
{|\mathbf{\dot{r}}|^3}$$

Comment: Are you saying that $\alpha(t)$ equals $\beta(t)$? I am confused. I am aware of the curvature function, but don't know how to represent $\beta(t)$.

Comment: No, simply compute everything from $\beta(t)$, you'll get $\kappa_{\beta}(t)$ and so as $\kappa_{\beta}(0)$.  Your formula takes $t_0=0$

Comment: But the $\beta(t)$ I have provided in the question is correct?

Comment: $s^3$ should read $t^3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
  \kappa &= \frac{\dot{x}\ddot{y}-\ddot{x}\dot{y}}{(\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2)^{3/2}} \\
  &= \frac{\left( 1-\dfrac{\kappa_0 t^2}{2} \right)(\kappa_0+\kappa_0't)-
           (-\kappa_0 t)\left( \kappa_0t+\dfrac{\kappa_0't^2}{2} \right)}
          {\left[ \left( 1-\dfrac{\kappa_0 t^2}{2} \right)^2+
           \left( \kappa_0t+\dfrac{\kappa_0't^2}{2} \right)^2 \right]^{3/2}} \\
  \kappa(0) &= \kappa_0
\end{align*}

Comment: Is it okay to take $t_0$ as $0$? I think the question is asking for $t_0$ to be arbitrary

Comment: Your power series expansion for $\beta$ is taking $t_0$ to be at $t=0$ (and also remember that here $t$ is the arclength parameter for $\alpha$).

Comment: @FelicioGrande, In general, $\beta(t)=\left( (t-t_0)-\dfrac{\kappa_{0} (t-t_0)^3}{6}+\ldots, \dfrac{\kappa_0 (t-t_0)^2}{2}+\dfrac{\kappa_0' (t-t_0)^3}{6}+\ldots \right)$